# Nvarchar conversion to decimal fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 database that stores decimals as Nvarchar(20). All fields are padded with spaces for some reason.

> Conversion fails with the following error:
>   "*Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
>
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.*"

I remove spaces with `RTRIM()`, replace the comma with dot using `REPLACE()` and convert by using `CAST()`. This line will fail. I added a second line without the casting just to inspect the value visually but couldn't see any reason for it to fail. I then uncommented my first line again and the casting worked. But only if the second line is together with it. I have no idea what's causing this.

```sql
SELECT
    CAST(REPLACE(RTRIM(nvarcharDecimalValue),',','.') AS DECIMAL(12,3)) as WillFailIfAlone,
    REPLACE(RTRIM(nvarcharDecimalValue),',','.') as NeedToBeHere
FROM myTable
```

The value I expect in return is any decimal number separated by a dot. Running the query with a manually inserted value alone works fine.

For example this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(REPLACE(RTRIM('                5,86'),',','.') AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS test
```

Comment: select column, try_cast(column AS DECIMAL(18,3)) from tablename

Comment: try_cast not available on SQL server 2008 R2 it seems. Only 2012 and up

Comment: Oops, but I think there's a similar functionality in older versions too.

Comment: Upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server and use `try_cast()` or `try_convert()`.